# Replacing comma with any special character in string using java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all the commas with any one special character (e.g "#") which are present inside the double quotes in java.

Below is the string :

```
String line="\"Lee, Rounded, Neck, Printed\",410.00,300.00,\"Red , Blue\",lee";
```

Output :

```
"Lee# Rounded# Neck# Printed",410.00,300.00,"Red # Blue",lee
```

I have tried this :

```
public class Str {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line="\"Lee, Rounded, Neck, Printed\",410.00,300.00,\"Red , Blue\",lee";
        String lineDelimiter=",";
        String templine=line;
      if(templine!=null && templine.contains("\""))
      {
          Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(\".*?"+Pattern.quote(lineDelimiter)+".*?\")");
          Matcher m=p.matcher(templine);
          if(m.find())
          {
              for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                  String Temp=m.group(i);
                  String Temp1=Temp;
                  Temp=Temp.replaceAll("(,)", " ## ");
                  line=line.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(Temp1),Pattern.quote(Temp));
              }
          }
      }
}
}
```

using above code i able to find only the first occurances of string present inside the quotes not second one("Red , Blue").

Comment: You don't need Regex to do a simple character replace, and it's also not difficult to do with Regex either, what's the problem you encountered?

Comment: The point is "inside double quotes". Nevertheless, what have you tried?

Comment: Have you considered using a CSV library?

Comment: @GiulioFranco i have not considered using CSV library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
String line="\"Lee, Rounded, Neck, Printed\",410.00,300.00,\"Red , Blue\",lee";
String repl = line.replaceAll(",(?!(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)", "#");
System.out.println("Replaced => " + repl);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"Lee# Rounded# Neck# Printed",410.00,300.00,"Red # Blue",lee
```

**Explanation:** This regex basically means match a comma if it is NOT followed by even number of double quotes. In other words match a comma if it is inside double quotes.

**PS:** Assuming there are no unbalanced double quotes and there is no case of escaped double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  String line="\"Lee, Rounded, Neck, Printed\",410.00,300.00,\"Red , Blue\",lee";
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line,"\"");
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2=new ArrayList<>();
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
        list.add(st.nextToken());
    }
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    while (m.find()) {
        list2.add(m.group(1));
    }

    for(String i:list){
       if(list2.contains(i)){
           sb.append(i.replaceAll(",","#"));
       }else{
           sb.append(i);
       }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the following should work (which means I haven't tested it):

```
//Catches contents of quotes
static final Pattern outer = Pattern.compile("\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\"");

private String replaceCommasInsideQuotes(String s) {
    StringBuilder bdr = new StringBuilder(s);
    Matcher m = outer.matcher(bdr);
    while (m.find()) {
        bdr.replace(m.start(), m.end(), m.group().replaceAll(",", "#"));
    }
    return bdr.toString();
}
```

Or the similar:

```
//Catches contents of quotes
static final Pattern outer = Pattern.compile("\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\"");

private String replaceCommasInsideQuotes(String s) {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = outer.matcher(bdr);
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(buff, "");
        buff.append(m.group().replaceAll(",", "#"));
    }
    m.appendTail(buff);
    return buff.toString();
}
```